# C program is printing to much

Tags: c, if-statement, boolean-expression

I am trying to run this program which asks the user for the two dates in the format mm/dd/yy. After the two are entered the program is supposed to compare the two dates to see which one is larger. The problem I am running into is that when i enter in the same date the code spits out that "The dates are the same." But it continues to print 1/1/1 is earlier than 1/1/1 (assuming 1/1/1 is the date entered twice). When the code is the same how do I skip the next code? I want the program to end after the same dates are entered.

Below is the code that I have so far. I am also using bool and not sure if I am using this correctly.

```
// Preprocessor directives
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>


// Call main function
int main (void)
{
    // Declare variables
    int d1, m1, y1, d2, m2, y2;
    bool first_date = true;

    // Prompt user to enter information
    printf("Enter first date (mm/dd/yy): ");
    scanf("%d /%d /%d", &m1, &d1, &y1);

    printf("Enter second date (mm/dd/yy): ");
    scanf("%d /%d /%d", &m2, &d2, &y2);

    // if/else statements for comparison
    if (y1 < y2)
        first_date = true;
    else if (y1 > y2)
        first_date = false;
    else if (m1 < m2)
        first_date = true;
    else if (m1 > m2)
        first_date = false;
    else if (d1 < d2)
        first_date = true;
    else if (d1 > d2)
        first_date = false;
    else 
        printf("The dates are the same.\n");

    if (first_date == true)
    {
        printf("%d/%d/%d is earlier ijijthan %d/%d/%d\n", m1, d1, y1, m2, d2, y2);
    }
    else if (first_date == false)
    {
        printf("%d/%d/%d is earlier than %d/%d/%d\n", m2, d2, y2, m1, d1, y1);
    }



    // End program
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Just return after the `printf("The dates are the same.\n");` ???

Comment: Note: do not compare with a boolean constant. This is hard to understand. Instead, use `if ( first_date )`. Best would be to use "talking" variable names, e.g. `first_date_is_earlier`.

Comment: I disagree with you. It's much clearer if it's a boolean or an integer. I mean explicit comparison. I like verbosity. Although the naming you suggest is better.

Comment: @iharob: `if ( first_date_is_earlier )` is clearly better to understand than `if ( first_date_is_earlier == true )`. Simply because you have to evaluate the expression in your mind, the first is almost natural language . The first version even my mother would understand (well, if she spoke english) the second not.

Comment: I understand your point and I even thing that you are right but I still feel comfortable reading it the second way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick fix would be to add another if statement around your last two if cases and use another bool. Then, when your program prints that the dates are the same, the bool could be updated. The modified program would look something like this:

```
// Preprocessor directives
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>


// Call main function
int main (void)
{
    // Declare variables
    int d1, m1, y1, d2, m2, y2;
    bool first_date = true;
    bool same = false; //NEW BOOL

    // Prompt user to enter information
    printf("Enter first date (mm/dd/yy): ");
    scanf("%d /%d /%d", &m1, &d1, &y1);

    printf("Enter second date (mm/dd/yy): ");
    scanf("%d /%d /%d", &m2, &d2, &y2);

    // if/else statements for comparison
    if (y1 < y2)
        first_date = true;
    else if (y1 > y2)
        first_date = false;
    else if (m1 < m2)
        first_date = true;
    else if (m1 > m2)
        first_date = false;
    else if (d1 < d2)
        first_date = true;
    else if (d1 > d2)
        first_date = false;
    else {
        printf("The dates are the same.\n");
        same = true; //CHANGE VALUE IF SAME
    }

    if(same == false){
        if (first_date == true)
        {
            printf("%d/%d/%d is earlier ijijthan %d/%d/%d\n", m1, d1, y1, m2, d2, y2);
        }
        else if (first_date == false)
        {
            printf("%d/%d/%d is earlier than %d/%d/%d\n", m2, d2, y2, m1, d1, y1);
        }
    }



    // End program
    return(0);
}
```

I think that this would work for you.

Comment: Thank you this clarifies the bool operation to end the program and I got my program to work for all cases with this answer. Could I have shortened the answers of the first_date == true to just be first_date. Since first_date is defined in my answer to be true. so i could change every case that I wanted to be false to !first_date correct?

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Yes, you can take out all of the 'first_date = true' cases actually because they aren't really doing anything. As you said, it is already set to true, so you just need to check for when you might want it to be false. In addition, if you have a long list of ifs and else ifs like this, you might want to write it as a switch statement. I personally wouldn't use '!first_date' because I think the ! is only used during comparisons, not when you are assigning something to be false.

Answer (score 1):

It's a logic problem, you need 3 states instead of two. Try like this

```
int result; /* 1 for <, 2 for > and 0 for equality */

result = 0; /* By default, they compare equal unless ... */
if (y1 < y2)
    result = 1;
else if (y1 > y2)
    result = 2;
else if (m1 < m2)
    result = 1;
else if (m1 > m2)
    result = 2;
else if (d1 < d2)
    result = 1;
else if (d1 > d2)
    result = 2;

switch (result)
{
case 1:
    printf("%d/%d/%d is earlier ijijthan %d/%d/%d\n", m1, d1, y1, m2, d2, y2);
    break;
case 2:
    printf("%d/%d/%d is earlier than %d/%d/%d\n", m2, d2, y2, m1, d1, y1);
    break;
case 3:
    printf("The dates are the same.\n");
    break;
}
```

Your program was behaving correctly since `first_date` was `true` when the program reached the `if (first_date ...` part.

Comment: I love the simplicity of the switch operation. This is essentially the same logic I wanted to say only using switch. I like the use of referencing to 0, 1, 2 for the result and then printing that result later. This makes the code easier to understand thanks for the input!

Comment: @AndrewDonaldStockton Well, this is something that comes from experience. I am very glad you liked it.